# Apple Watch 3px minimum left/right padding/margin?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfaceimage

Hey I am trying to display a picture "full screen" on the Apple Watch. However, it's not using the full width, there are like 2 pixels padding/margin on each side. How to remove this?

I've already tried putting the WKInterfaceImage in a group and then remove the insets but that also didn't work.

In the simulator, the width is 3px per side. I've tried 3 different pictures, same results.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the insets on your interface controller. Try setting them to custom and making them all 0.